# In ReactNative using Google place search autocomplete ..description result that hiding my screen component

Tags: react-native, search, native

```
import {
  GooglePlacesAutocomplete,
} from 'react-native-google-places-autocomplete';
```

Comment: Hello, looks like you are new to SO. Looking at your question it is very hard to understand what you need help with. Please do take a look at our [how to ask guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It helps us help you!

Comment: ee mair edapaad